# проблемы с кодировкой при скачивание файла php

Tags: php, кодировка

скачиваю с сервера `DOC` файл, но после скачивания в файле весь текст становится иероглифами. Предположил, что проблемы с кодировкой, но не знаю как решить. Код:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: `$file` откуда взялся?

Comment: это путь к файлу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему убрав `BOM` во всех файлах, для этого использовал программу `recoder`, даёт возможность автоматически убрать `BOM` во всех файлах. вдруг кому поможет.